# Use Taiko drum for random games

Tags: pc, controllers, emulation, windows-10

I bought a cool rhythm game (Taiko no Tatsujin) and I got the drum controller to go with it. While playing with it I thought it would be fun to try and use it for games obviously not made for this kind of controller.

I thought about it and after a little bit of testing with my computer and switch, there are only 4 total buttons (besides the ones that are used for a normal controller), and I would love to be able to hit 2 of the buttons at once and it register as a 3rd press kind of like how the game I got the drum for works. Basically if I'm using an NES emulator I would like to be able to hit the drum in both the middle parts to register an A press or something similar to that.

Is there a method available to register a multi-button combo on my controller as a different button entirely on the controller? (E.g. X = A, Y = B, Z = A+B)?

Further information: I would like this to work for the JNES, SNES9x, and VisualBoyAdvance emulators at this time. Having to use a different emulator for these systems is okay too.

Comment: Reading this carefully, I don't think it's an actual recommendation question (i.e. 'what's a good NES emulator?), but rather 'how do I use my taiko drum as an NES controller on my pc?' albeit worded somewhat poorly. Technical questions about controllers are on-topic, so I've tried to edit your question to be more on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

**You need a joystick/keyboard conversion application**

Instead of trying to find an emulator that supports a strange controller...

Get yourself a joystick conversion application, like [joy2key](https://joytokey.net/en/), [Xpadder](https://xpadder.com/) (windows, shareware), [keysticks](https://keysticks.net) (Windows, EPL) or [AntimicroX](https://github.com/juliagoda/antimicroX) (linux, open-source). Free versions exist of both XPadder and joy2key, but they are not as up-to-date and may miss features. These are just a few examples of these remapping programs.

These programs can convert joystick inputs (even multiple key combinations via their advanced settings) to keyboard inputs. Then you configure your emulator for keyboard and can use multiple-button combos as single button presses on the drum.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out in a little bit, it seems like its what i needed for this strange idea lmao.

Comment: As far as I've tried with this, and I've tried for at least half an hour to an hour so far, I can't find an option in the emulator *or* the joystick conversion application. For you to know I am using JoyToKey Version 5.2.1 and Jnes Version 1.2. I'll keep trying to look at tutorials and trial an error. If I somehow get this over with I'll come back.